# Passing data from a WinForms application to MVC3

Tags: vb.net, winforms, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am working on an application that has a Winforms and MVC3 Web component. We need to be able upload large files from the desktop to the web. I have tried the various VB 2010 WebClient and FTP FileUpload alternatives but continue to run into permission issues, even though the User-ID and password I supply are the same as those used by an FTP application that successfully copies files to the same MVC3 site.

In my efforts to find alternative solutions, I have looked into using WCF which also seems complicated and problematic for this particular application.

The closest I have come to a solution utilizes HttpWebRequest on the Winforms application. The following VB 2010 and C# code (MVC3) successfully passes the Filename and File data to MVC3 (the InputStream contains the references and UrlEncode data, but the class containing the fields for this data are null. (I have also passed just the file data without the filename, and the uploaded file is successfully created from the InputStream - but the method variable is still null). Although I could pick apart the InputStream, I would prefer a more elegant alternative.

VB 2010 Winforms method:

```
    Public Shared Sub FileUpload(ByVal Filepath As String)
    Try
        Dim Host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Host")
        Dim url As String = Path.Combine(Host, "UI/FileUpload")
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim Filename As String = Path.GetFileName(Filepath)
        Dim FileData As Byte() = GetFile2UploadData(Filepath)
        Dim data As String = String.Format("FileName={0}&FileData={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Filename), System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FileData))
        request.ContentLength = data.Length
        Using sr As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream)
            sr.Write(data)
        End Using
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return
End Sub
```

MVC3 C# Controller method and class:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(FileInformation fi) 
{
  try 
  {
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Users/User1"), fi.FileName), FileMode.Create)) {
        fs.Write(fi.FileData,0,fi.FileData.Length);
      }
      return Content("OK");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
public class FileInformation
{
  public string FileName;
  public byte[] FileData; 
}
```

I have been chewing on this problem for several days now. Your incisive ideas are appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop machines are on the same network as your web site, it would be much easier and more efficient to create a shared directory on the web server and have your desktop applications use standard file copy operations to get the files there.

You could then notify the MVC app that a new file has arrived through code similar to what you have already.

Comment: I don't know about efficient. Maintaining permissions can be a problem with an upload folder as anyone could see/change what had been uploaded. Granted you could set up some fruity permissions to make the folder write-only.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: By efficient, I meant for throughput of the web site since you would eliminate the flow of the file data through IIS. We use this approach extensively, although the file transfer is actually performed through an internal-only application server so that we don't have to worry about the authentication issues or impact on the main web site.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since uploading files will occur very infrequently, using the same web server for the upload process is not worrisome in terms of performance. I believe I need to research MVC model-binding for elegant parameter passing from external applications like WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

A WCF service would feel better to me. You can specify the parameter on the service as `byte[]`. You'd just need to set the maximum request & message size, which you'd have to do for the web app as well.

If you're going to write a web app, I think you need to change the content type to multipart/form-data. you should then be able to look in the `Request.Files` collection

Comment: The multipart/form-data did turn out to be the way to go for this VB WinForms application. I did need to structure the Request to conform to the content-type rules for multipart form-data that includes boundry specification. On the server side, Request.Files did the trick. Thanks for your input.